# DataFrame values frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which I want to find value frequencies through all the frame.

```
    a   b
0   5   7
1   7   8
2   5   7
```

The result should be like:

```
 5 2
 7 3
 8 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
s = df.stack().value_counts().sort_index()
```

Or [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
s = df.melt()['value'].value_counts().sort_index()
print (s)
5    2
7    3
8    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

a simple way is to use `pd.Series` for finding the unique count:

```
import pandas as pd

# creating the series
s = pd.Series(data = [5,10,9,8,8,4,5,9,10,0,1])  
# finding the unique count
print(s.value_counts())
```

output:

```
10    2
9     2
8     2
5     2
4     1
1     1
0     1
```